# My program runs, but when I try to do calculations it crashes

Tags: android

This is the code I am using, It runs perfectly fine but when I input numbers for the calcuation and then press to calculate the program crashes. Please help me. I've tried rewriting the program, I've created a new program yet it still crashes.

```
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;    

import static java.lang.Double.parseDouble;

public class MedicalCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {
    double conversionRate = 2.2;
    double weightEntered;
    double convertedWeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_medical_calculator);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
        final RadioButton lbToKilo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radLbToKilo);
        final RadioButton kiloToLb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radKiloToLb);
        final TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResults);
        Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
        convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                weightEntered= parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                DecimalFormat tenth = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                if(lbToKilo.isChecked()){
                    if(weightEntered<=500){
                        convertedWeight = weightEntered/conversionRate;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MedicalCalculator.this,"Pounds must be less than 500" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                if (kiloToLb.isChecked()){
                    if (weightEntered <=225){
                        convertedWeight=weightEntered*conversionRate;
                        result.setText(tenth.format(convertedWeight)+" Pounds");
                    }else {
                        Toast.*make*Text(MedicalCalculator.this`, "Kilos must be less than 225", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }};
```

This is the XML File (*`layout_width`, `layout_height`, `textColor`, `textSize`, margins, and paddings omitted*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_medical_calculator"
    tools:context="com.example.andersonmoonguaklang.medicalcalculator.MedicalCalculator">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txtTitle"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/btnConvert"
        android:id="@+id/btnConvert"
      />

    <RadioGroup
        android:checkedButton="@+id/radLbToKilo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWeight"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtTitle">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/radLbToKilo"
            android:id="@+id/radLbToKilo"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/radKiloToLb"
            android:id="@+id/radKiloToLb"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTitle"
        tools:ignore="TextFields" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:id="@+id/txtResults"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the error message you get in Android studio LogCat window. Press `Alt + 6` if you can't find the window.

Comment: Constant repeat of this line: 02-12 07:00:56.331 6017-6031/system_process I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...

Comment: Post the messages you get when the app crashes. Post it in your question description.

Comment: When the program closes, it says "Unfortunately, MedicalCalculator has stopped"

Comment: Removed unnecessary clutter